# How to find the smallest sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ be an outcome space. Let $X$ be a function defined on $\Omega$ given as $$X(\omega)  = \begin{cases} 5 \quad \text{when $\omega = 1,8$} \\
> \pi \quad \text{when $\omega = 2,3,4,5,6,7$}
> \end{cases} $$
> Find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $F$ that makes $X$ into a random variable.

I know that the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is that:

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$
2. If $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A^C \in \mathcal{F}$.
3. If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\cup_1^{\infty} A_i \in \mathcal{F}$

My initial thought is that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra would be $\{ \emptyset, (\{1\} \cup \{8\} ), (\{1\} \cup \{8\} )^C \}$. My reasoning is that the complement of $(\{1\} \cup \{8\} )$ would be all numbers $2,3,...,7$. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: What about $\emptyset^c$?... i.e $\Omega$

Comment: Indeed, you must first find out what $A:=X^{-1}(\{5\})=\{X=5\}$ and $B:=X^{-1}(\{\pi\})=\{X=\pi\}$ are. So the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ that makes $X$ a random variable must contain the events $\emptyset$, $\Omega$, $A$, and $B$. Now, is $\{\emptyset,A,B,\Omega\}$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$?

Comment: You can write $\{1\}\cup \{8\}$ as just $\{1,8\}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, it is easy to check that the smallest sigma algebra which makes a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ a random variable is:

$\{X^{-1}(B): B\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$

Where $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. In your case, if $B$ contains $5$ but not $\pi$ its inverse image is $\{1,8\}$. If it contains $\pi$ but not $5$ then the inverse image is $\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. If it contains both then the inverse image is $\Omega$, and if it contains none of them then the inverse image is the empty set. So the sigma algebra is:

$\{\emptyset, \{1,8\}, \{2,3,4,5,6,7\}, \Omega \}$

Comment: More generally, if $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a function with finite range $\{x_i: 1\le i\le n\}$, then the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ that makes $X$ a random variable is $$\mathcal F:=\left\{\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i:I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}\right\},$$ where $A_i:=X^{-1}(\{x_i\})=\{X=x_i\}$.